# When does a web page appear the first time?

Tags: events, dom, web, load

I'd like to know when does a web page appear the first time, especially in relation with events like the DOMContentLoaded or or the Load event.

If I knew the event in question then I could minimize the HTTP requests up until that point and lazy-load resources after that. My knowledge on the subject is admittedly limited and I know that it's a very broad topic but I'd rather like some practical info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en), this is the general sequence of events:

> 1. Process HTML markup and build the DOM tree.
> 2. Process CSS markup and build the CSSOM tree.
> 3. Combine the DOM and CSSOM into a render tree.
> 4. Run layout on the render tree to compute geometry of each node.
> 5. Paint the individual nodes to the screen.

[According to Google again](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp?hl=en),

> - **domContentLoaded** typically marks when both the DOM and CSSOM are ready.

Together, I would say that in general, `DOMContentLoaded` is the closest event related to the painting of the markup, and `Load` is the closest event to when the rendering **and** loading of external resources is finished.

But, this could vary based on browser implementation, HTML version (4, 5, etc.), and probably other things I'm not thinking about.